# allow special characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to allow special characters including ' in MySQL. I have a "bio" text field which allows user data and I am using the POST method.
My PHP is included:

```
    $uid = $_POST["UID"];
    $bio = $_POST["bio"];

    $update_query = "UPDATE `User` SET bio = '$bio' WHERE uid = '$uid';";
    $conn->query( $update_query );
    $conn->close()
```

All the users are verified so there should be no danger in allowing them to use special characters. How can I update my code?

Comment: look into prepared statements

Comment: @rtfm I'd suggest using prepared statements over linking an answer that escapes input ;-)

Comment: Using prepared statements will properly escape the special characters and help prevent SQL Injection (as mentioned by others)

Comment: many a way to skin a cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the string by using the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function. Here is some [Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp). Basically, you pass in a connection and a string, and it returns a safe string to input into your database.

In your case you would do something like this:

```
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["UID"]);
$bio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["bio"]);
```

ps: you should always use mysqli in php

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it to work

Comment: A better approach is to use prepared statements with placeholders in the query. This is always better than escaping. You also said that you should always use mysqli (as OP is using), that's fine to use (as long as you prepare and bind!!), but pdo is just as valid as mysqli. There's not necessarily a right or wrong between those.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex Tartan is absolutely correct, you should be using prepared statements.  Not only do they solve this problem completely, but they go a long way toward protecting you from malicious users.  Here's an example:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'my_database';
$user = 'my_username';
$pass = 'my_password';
$charset = 'utf8';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$stmt=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE `User` SET bio = :bio WHERE uid = :uid");
$stmt->bindParam('bio', $_POST['bio']);
$stmt->bindParam('uid', $_POST['UID']);
$stmt->execute();
```

The reason this is so valuable is the variable values (e.g., the contents of `$_POST['bio']`) are sent to the database seperate from the SQL query.  Thus, they need no special treatment and may contain pretty much anything your character set allows.